# require_once not throwing any errors - white screen of death

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to load models via the following function.... I'm running into an issue where require_once is killing the page.  The following code does NOT echo "not there", meaning the file must exist.

```
protected function modelFactory ($model, $input = array()) {
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
    require_once APPPATH.'models/'.str_replace('.', '/', strtolower($model)).'.php';
    exit('test'); //doesn't show, but if it's above require_once it does...

    $class = str_replace('.', '', $model).'Model';
    return new $class($input);
}
```

I can't think of what could be supressing any error messages coming out of this function that's preventing the rest of the page from loading

Comment: What's with your `display_errors` configuration directive?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.... the configuration for `error_reporting()` came with CodeIgniter

Comment: `var_dump(ini_get('display_errors'));`

Comment: output is: `string '1' (length=1)`

Answer (score 2):

The exit keyword will prevent the program from running.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: Ah, we missed OP's edit `The following code does NOT echo "not there", meaning the file must exist.` +1 however for checking the simple things first

Comment: That is only debug code to showcase that I did echo the environment to verify.  It's not in the code I'm working with.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out... the class I was loading is built to extend another class which wasn't loaded on the page.  I'm still unsure why it didn't throw any errors...